# How to echo a attribute label in woocommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, attributes, woocommerce

Im trying to echo the products attribute labels inside a class in a woocommerce loop.
I have tried:

```
class="<?php echo wc_attribute_label( $name ); ?>"
```

but it doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for any help possible!

Kind regards,
Richard

Comment: Shouldn't it be `echo wc_attribute_label( $name, $product );`?

Comment: Hi marekful and thanks for the reposne! Hmm... I tried this:

    <?php echo wc_attribute_label( $name, $product ); ?>
But it dosent echo anything. :(

Comment: Where is this loop running - main products query? From a child theme file? from your functions.php file? A custom query?

Comment: in the main shop loop i would say. In content-product.php.


  <div class="product_after_shop_loop">
  
  <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title' ); ?>
  
  <div class="product_after_shop_loop_switcher">
   
   <div class="product_after_shop_loop_price">
    <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title_loop_price' ); ?>
   </div>
   
   <div class="product_after_shop_loop_buttons">
    <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item' ); ?>
    <div class="<?php echo wc_attribute_label( $name ); ?>">+ färger</div>
   </div>
   
  </div>
  
 </div>

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Kharis Sulistiyono i got this answer in the wordpress/woocommerce forums:

```
<?php
global $product;
$attribute = $product->get_attributes();

$attribute_arr = array();

if( count($attribute) > 0 ){
    foreach ($attribute as $key => $value) {
        $attribute_arr[] = $key;
    }
}

$attributes = implode($attribute_arr, ' ');
?>

/* Print as class value */
class="<?php echo esc_attr($attributes); ?>";
```

It works like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
$term = get_term_by( 'name', $variation_product->get_attribute( 'pa_color' ), 'pa_color' );
```

This gives you a term object, so if you for instance want the labels slug you can just:

```
echo $term->slug;
```

Or ID:

```
echo $term->id;
```